# VS Code Ruby on Rails Completion and Docstrings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Im using VS Code to develop a ruby on rails application, but one thing that has been driving me aboslutely crazy is that there is little to no useful information in VS code.

I have tried every extension i can find... I have Ruby, ruby solargraph, ruby-symbols, tabnine, vscode ruby etc

Whenever i do something such ass in a migration, try to add a column:

```
add_column(:items, :note, :string)
```

I get absolutely no information. Autocmplete doesnt seem to have a clue that add_column exists, and once i type it out i get no indication of what parameters it takes, no doc strings are available, and if i try to go to definition, it fails and does nothing.

Is this normal for ruby/ruby on rails? Shouldn't i be able to get some info on what im using, at any point? This doesnt work for any call im trying.

This also goes for things like:
`resources :chefs, except [:new]`

I have no idea what im doing when i start this, because "except" doesnt get completed as if its a known thing I can do